# id to fields in jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a table and I have multiple text boxes in a column.I am add rows to the table using jquery clone method

```
var row = $('#nameTable tbody>tr:last').clone(true);
```

Now I want to add ids to the text fields of the new row.
Any help?

Comment: Possible duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2977041/changing-various-ids-after-cloning-in-jquery

Comment: [Java is to Javascript what Car is to Carpet](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/245062/whats-the-difference-between-javascript-and-java): They both start with _java_, but they are completely unrelated.

Answer (score 3):

Just add attribute   `id` to that new `row` object.

```
  $(row).find('input').attr("id","newId");
```

Docs of [`attr()`](http://api.jquery.com/attr/)

note: Considering only one input element is there in your new object. If multiple input elements are there, you have to loop on them and have assign individual id's to them, Since Id must be **unique**.

Comment: Almost, you are now adding the id to the row, OP wanted to add id to the inputs so it should be `$(row).find('input').attr("id","newId");`

Answer (score 0):

Try with this

```
var row = $('#nameTable tbody>tr:last').clone(true);
row.find("#someInput").attr("id","someInput_2");
```

Comment: Thanks a lot friends for the help

Answer (score 0):

Since you referring to text fields you can make use of this selector

```
$(row).find('input[type=text]').each(function(element) {
    element.attr("id","newId");
})
```

Answer (score 0):

For set multiple IDs use (be careful, because ID must be unique):

```
var row = $('#nameTable tbody>tr:last').clone(true);

row.find(':text').each(function () {
    this.id = 'new_id' + Math.random();
});
```

I prefer access to ID via pure javascript instead of jquery http://jsperf.com/browser-diet-this-attr-id-vs-this-id/12